# Remove parent element of a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

My Array looks like this:

```
    Array ( 

      [Team] => Array ( 

        [0] => Array ( 

          [Name] => Team A [Played] => 0 [Wins] => 0 [Draws] => 0 [Losses] => 0 [Gd] => 0 [Points] => 0 ) 

        [1] => Array ( 

          [Name] => Team B [Played] => 0 [Wins] => 0 [Draws] => 0 [Losses] => 0 [Gd] => 0 [Points] => 0 ) ) )
```

I want to be able to remove a team with a particular name, say Team A.

Comment: How are you generating the array? Might be easier to get all teams that aren't "Team A" rather than filtering it afterwards

Comment: XML, basically i want to update the teams values, but finding it easier to push a new array onto the end and just want to delete the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I, myself always like to use a foreach loop instead of counting and using a for loop. Just my preference. Also, In one of the previous answers it was recommended to use array_splice, however unset works better here - unless you are wanting to put the removed team into a new array, which is what you'd typically use array_splice for. Unset would, I believe, save some memory.

```
$remove = 'Team A';    
foreach ($teams['Team'] as $key => $team) {
    if($team['Name'] == $remove){
       unset($teams['Team'][$key]);
    }        
}
```

Comment: Easier and more stable with `foreach($.. as $k=>$v)`.

Comment: @VolkerK, what do you mean "easier and more stable"? Why is that more stable? And why is it easier, considering you need `$i` anyway? I tend to `avoid` foreach in cases like this, because it can lead you to try to unset `$team`, which doesn't work.

Comment: a) Why do you need $i? `b) foreach(... as $k=>$v)` also works for arrays like `(2=>x, 7=>y, 'foo'=>z)` -> stable code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop the array by index, backwards, until you find the target team name, then use [`array_splice`](http://php.net/array_splice) to remove the parent:

```
$lastIndex = count($arr['Team'])-1;
for($i=$lastIndex; $i>=0; $i--) {
    if($arr['Team'][$i]['Name'] == 'Team A') {
        array_splice($arr['Team'], $i, 1);
    }
}
```

You can also use [`unset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php):

```
$lastIndex = count($arr['Team'])-1;
for($i=$lastIndex; $i>=0; $i--) {
    if($arr['Team'][$i]['Name'] == 'Team A') {
        unset($arr['Team'][$i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to use the key `'Team'` inside the loop. Answer updated. I also added another option, using `unset` instead of `array_splice`.

Comment: Some reason both the for loops are crashing, not sure why

Comment: There was a stupid syntax error (missing `$` on the second `$lastIndex`). Now fixed. See [working example on codepad](http://codepad.org/WLhKMvuq).

Answer (score 0):

"XML, basically i want to update the teams values, but finding it easier to push a new array onto the end and just want to delete the old one" - it *can* be as easy as

```
<?php
$foo = new SimpleXMLElement(getData());
foreach( $foo->xpath('teams/team[@name="Team A"]') as $t) {
    $t->wins += 1;
}
echo $foo->asxml();


function getData() {
    return <<< eox
<foo>
    <teams>
        <team name="Team A">
            <played>0</played>
            <wins>0</wins>
            <draws>0</draws>
            <looses>0</looses>
        </team>
        <team name="Team B">
            <played>0</played>
            <wins>0</wins>
            <draws>0</draws>
            <looses>0</looses>
        </team>
    </teams>
</foo>  
eox;
}
```

prints

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
    <teams>
        <team name="Team A">
            <played>0</played>
            <wins>1</wins>
            <draws>0</draws>
            <looses>0</looses>
        </team>
        <team name="Team B">
            <played>0</played>
            <wins>0</wins>
            <draws>0</draws>
            <looses>0</looses>
        </team>
    </teams>
</foo>
```